# can't download php on macos

Tags: php, homebrew

when i write `brew install php` i get this error:

tar: Ignoring malformed pax extended attribute
tar: Ignoring malformed pax extended attribute
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
Error: Failure while executing; `/usr/bin/env tar --extract --no-same-owner --file /Users/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/592c007136b235b78c9fa8eafda449719cdea58e2a4afe18b9a445cd0050ba1b--doxygen-1.9.7.src.tar.gz --directory /private/tmp/d20230608-43989-1hef8mk` exited with 1. Here's the output:
tar: Ignoring malformed pax extended attribute
tar: Ignoring malformed pax extended attribute
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.

I don't know how to fix. I already reinstalled homebrew and still doesn't help.

It is not clear how to fix the error and get the latest version of php.

I tried everything in Google, all the commands, I have macos mojave(

Answer (score 0):

It can be difficult to tell what the issue is solely from that part of the error; however, I had a similar message and the issue was the there was **not enough disk space to extract the files**.